# How do I return an array of int to a main method

Tags: java, arrays, return

```
public static int[] getLottoNumberGenerator()
{
    int[] numberGenerator = new int[9];
    {
        numberGenerator[0] = (int) ((9 * Math.random()) +1);
        numberGenerator[1] = (int) ((9 * Math.random()) +1);
        numberGenerator[2] = (int) ((9 * Math.random()) +1);
        numberGenerator[3] = (int) ((9 * Math.random()) +1);
        numberGenerator[4] = (int) ((9 * Math.random()) +1);
        numberGenerator[5] = (int) ((9 * Math.random()) +1);
        numberGenerator[6] = (int) ((9 * Math.random()) +1);
        numberGenerator[7] = (int) ((9 * Math.random()) +1);
        numberGenerator[8] = (int) ((9 * Math.random()) +1);
    }
    return numberGenerator;
```

When I return `numberGenerator`, I get a series of letters, numbers and other characters.

How can I edit my code to return 9 (int) to the main method? I already tried `return numberGenerator[0]` but it doesn't work.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: main method?. Where is your main method?

Comment: Your question could be improved. In the future, please show how you call the method, and show exactly what returns. Why make people guess? You've gotten the correct answer this time from Makato, but in the future you likely won't be so lucky unless your question is better, is more complete.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It **is** returning your array with valid data in it.  (Although I question the necessity of the curly braces after you instantiate your array, in which you populate the data.)

What you're likely doing is printing out the result of the call:

```
System.out.println(getLottoNumberGenerator());
```

That's not going to work; it'll print out the array's default `toString`, which would look something like `[I@827328`.  Not helpful at all.

What you want to do instead is wrap that in a call to [`Arrays.toString()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#toString%28int%5b%5d%29).

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(getLottoNumberGenerator());
```